# How to change the button based on the user input?

Tags: python, django

I am implementing a pypi package called django-shopping-card https://pypi.org/project/django-shopping-cart/, so the users can see their saved posts.
My issue is that I could not make the button to display "Remove Post" instead of "Add to Card", if the post was added already. I have tried to create a different method to pass the posts which have been saved, but that caused a an error, as I cannot access the key and values of the cart without for loop. I am new to this and I would highly appreciate any comments and suggestions.

```
def add_fav(request, id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    post = Auction.objects.get(id=id)
    cart.add(product=post)
    return redirect("watchlist")


def item_clear(request, id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = Auction.objects.get(id=id)
    cart.remove(product)
    return redirect("watchlist")


def items_clear(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    cart.clear()
    return redirect("watchlist")


def get_cart(request):
    return render(request, 'auctions/watchlist.html', {'cart': Cart(request)})


listings.html

{% block body %}
    {% for auction in object_list %}
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card mb-2">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title"><a href="{% url 'listing' auction.pk %}">{{ auction.name }}</a></h5>
                        Price: {{ auction.price }}<br>
                        <p class="card-text">{{ auction.description|slice:":10"  }} ...</p>
                        {{ auction.author }}
                        Category: {{ auction.category }}
                        <hr><img class="card-img-top" src="{{ auction.image.url }}" alt="no" ><br>
                            {% for key,value in request.session.cart.items|slice:1 %} <br>
                                {% if value.product_id == auction.id %}
                                    - <a href="{% url 'remove_fav' value.product_id%}">Delete</a>
                                {% endif %}
                     {% endfor %}
                        <a class="btn btn-primary" id="add_card" href="{% url 'add_fav' auction.id %}"
                           style="margin-top: 10px; ">Add to card</a><br>
                    </div>
            {{ text }}
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: it's hard to help because in your question, you say "I could not make the button to display 'Remove Post' instead of 'Add to Card'", but there is no 'remove post' inside your code, so I'm not sure where, exactly, you are referring to. You have a 'remove_fav' url call with 'Delete' text, is that the part you meant?

Comment: - <a href="{% url 'remove_fav' value.product_id%}">Delete</a> - here is the code I am using to delete the blog post from the favorites, it is being passed to item_clear function inside the view

Comment: and what error are you getting?

Comment: This is more like a logical one, I would like to remove  "Add to card" button if the user has added the post to his favourite posts through this button and display "Remove post"button instead of it

Comment: your view should do the logic checking regarding what the current user has or hasn't already done, and send the results in the context to the template; then all your template does is a conditional check with if on the contents in the context, branching as desired. I don't have time right now to rewrite your code into this format, perhaps later.